# Initialialize a property in a command

Tags: c#, wpf, command, nullreferenceexception

I have a `ViewModel` (`UserControlViewModel`) with a command:

```
public Command PressMeCommand { get; set; }
```

As well as:

```
#region Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged


    private File _myfile;
    public File MyFile
    {
        get
        {
            return _myfile;
        }
        set
        {
            value = _myfile;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyFile");
        }
    }
```

Where `File` is my class with a method called `read()`.

I'm adding to my `allMyControls ObservableCollection<UserControlViewModel>` with another command bound to a button placed in my MainWindow. The following code is from **RootViewModel.cs**

```
private void AddUserControl()
    {
        UserControlViewModel myNewControl = new UserControlViewModel();
        myNewControl.PressMeCommand = new Command(() => OnUserControlPressed(myNewControl ));
        allMyControls.Add(myNewControl );
    }
```

Finally I'm setting the new Command:

```
private void OnUserControlPressed(UserControlViewModel item)
        {

            if (item != null)
            {
                item.MyFile.read();
                Num = item.MyFile.channels.Count;
            }
        }
```

It gives me an error "NullReferenceException was unhandled" when I press the button corresponding to PressMeCommand. My first reaction was, oh, I haven't initilialized MyFile so I moved to this:

```
private void OnUserControlPressed(UserControlViewModel item)
    {

        if (item != null)
        {
            item.MyFile = new File();
            item.MyFile.read(); //Here is the problem
            Num = item.MyFile.channels.Count;
        }
    }
```

But the problem persists. Now I'm completely out of ideas. What could it be? How to initialize properly my property `MyFile`?

Comment: Where do you initialize `channels`?

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: In the read() method.

Comment: I've edited the question with a comment near to the end showing where is the problematic line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got `value = _myfile;` in property setter. You need to reverse this of course.

Comment: And this is why you shouldn't be more than 10 hours in front a computer in a row. Thank you!!